# Twitter Streaming API confusion

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am completely confused  by Twitter streaming API behavior.  I created a simple stream with a 1 follow for "ESPN:

and get this tweet ( see attached) . which is a retweet, but the original is "ESPN FC" , not "ESPN"

what the heck is going on here ?  Why does twitter streaming API return this status ?

```html
{ "extended_entities": { "media": [ { "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/y2E7ktezgd", "source_user_id": 18091004, "type": "photo", "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/ECfRaipX4AA-_-S.jpg", "source_status_id": 1164129284480483329, "url": "<placeholder_url>",
"indices": [ 44, 67 ], "sizes": { "small": { "w": 544, "h": 680, "resize": "fit" }, "large": { "w": 1080, "h": 1350, "resize": "fit" }, "thumb": { "w": 150, "h": 150, "resize": "crop" }, "medium": { "w": 960, "h": 1200, "resize": "fit" } }, "id_str":
"1164129282605703168", "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/1164129284480483329/photo/1", "source_status_id_str": "1164129284480483329", "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ECfRaipX4AA-_-S.jpg", "id": 1164129282605703168, "source_user_id_str":
"18091004" } ] }, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "created_at": "Wed Aug 21 14:19:49 +0000 2019", "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "source": "<a href=\ "http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\ "nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
  "retweeted_status": {
    "extended_entities": {
      "media": [
        {
          "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/y2E7ktezgd",
          "indices": [
            32,
            55
          ],
          "sizes": {
            "small": {
              "w": 544,
              "h": 680,
              "resize": "fit"
            },
            "large": {
              "w": 1080,
              "h": 1350,
              "resize": "fit"
            },
            "thumb": {
              "w": 150,
              "h": 150,
              "resize": "crop"
            },
            "medium": {
              "w": 960,
              "h": 1200,
              "resize": "fit"
            }
          },
          "id_str": "1164129282605703168",
          "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/1164129284480483329/photo/1",
          "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ECfRaipX4AA-_-S.jpg",
          "id": 1164129282605703168,
          "type": "photo",
          "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/ECfRaipX4AA-_-S.jpg",
          "url": "<url>"
        }
      ]
    },
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "created_at": "Wed Aug 21 10:57:04 +0000 2019",
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"https://www.spredfast.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">Spredfast app<\/a>",
    "retweet_count": 2773,
    "retweeted": false,
    "geo": null,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "id_str": "1164129284480483329",
 .....
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any attachment here. Have you asked on the Twitter Developer forums? https://twittercommunity.com - also, can you share a code sample? Are you following the ESPN account, or tracking the term?

Comment: The Stackoverflow not letting me attach the json.. still grappling with it

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but an observation. Twitter appears to link all accounts that begin with ESPN.

Type this URL into a browser https://twitter.com/ESPN/status/1164129284480483329 
It will forward you to the original tweet at https://twitter.com/ESPNFC/status/1164129284480483329

The same occurs with non-ESPN user "ESPNSUCKS"
https://twitter.com/ESPNSUCKS/status/1164129284480483329

And also with XESPN which is a suspended account
https://twitter.com/XESPN/status/1164129284480483329

Comment: When searching usernames , the query takes a userId , in this case 2557521  How do they know that it is linked to other ESPN accounts?

Comment: No clue. The above is just an observation that probably is related to what you are experiencing with the API. Try posting your quesiton on the Twitter developer forum https://twittercommunity.com/c/streaming-apis

Comment: No , I think if you have a valid tweet id in the end, Twitter will redirect you to the tweet. Say your original URL was : https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1164543211660042241  and you replace tweet id with the one from ESPN  like so , https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1164129284480483329  . Twitter will redirect you to the ESPNFC tweet.

Comment: Interesting. I see that too. Did you post your question on the forum?

Comment: I did , Twitter is notorious for not caring for developer community. I doubt anything will come out of it.